# Use Windows Authentication in WCF on Http Post Methods only

Tags: wcf, http-post, windows-authentication

I've set up a restful WCF service that provides images to anyone that needs them (they are not security sensitive) but I would like to be able to use apps within the local domain that push images to the service and the service saves them for people to access externally.

So I'd like post methods only to require Windows Authentication, is this possible and if so, any idea how to do it please?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[Authorize]` and `[HttpPost]` before the method, like:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Method()
```

This article has all you need to know 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs

Comment: I'm not using MVC though, it is a restful WCF web service but not MVC.